# Custom data prediction using decision trees

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using `train_test_split` to train the model and check the results using `predict`. How do I proceed to predict the labels of additional data, for example, from a test set or from user inputs?

Comment: You can also use predict function to get prediction  on single observation. I assume that by prediction you mean predict function from sklearn package

Comment: `train_test_split` splits a dataset into datasets for training and testing. After your model is trained you can save it and use the `predict()` method to evaluate new data no matter where it comes from just as long as it follows the format of the training data.

Comment: I edited the question to improve the formulation to reflect how I (and apparently others) understood it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom data for prediction as long as it has the same number, order and type of features as your training data into an `array` type, not in `list`. If you meet these conditions, you can send that array to the model for prediction with the normal `predict()` method.